# ACPI PCC probe failed ... intel_soc_dts_thermal: request_threaded_irq ret -22

Tags: boot, 15.04, gui, acpi

I use Ubuntu 15.04 and Windows 8.1 (native) on a Medion Microstar AkoyaE6239. I started with Ubuntu 14.10 and then updated it.

The problem I describe here also happened in 14.10, and I tried to solve it, but somehow, after some days, I started the PC and the problem disappeared for no apparent reason.

Yesterday, while using Ubuntu, it suddenly shutted down, and when I rebooted it I had this problem after selecting Ubuntu in the GRUB menu:

First it says

```
error: invalid mode specification "text".
booting in blind mode
```

and then the command line interface appears with this error:

(My screen is also broken, so I can not type all the error parts. the "[...]" parts are these parts. Sorry.).

```
[    1[...]995] ACPI PCC probe failed.
starti[...]rsion 219
[  12..[...]2] intel_soc_dts_thermal: request_threaded_irq ret -22
```

Then the purple Ubuntu graphic loading splash image starts checking filesystems, it says this:

```
Press [...] cancel all filesystem checks in progress
Checking [...]gress on 1 disk (6.1% complete)
```

And then it goes back to the CLI, like this:

```
[    1[...]995] ACPI PCC probe failed.
starti[...]rsion 219
[  12..[...]2] intel_soc_dts_thermal: request_threaded_irq ret -22
Welcome to [...]mergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemtl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try again to boot into default mode.
Give root password for maintenane
(or type Control-D to ccontinue):
```

This is the error. I can log in and use the system, but only in the CLI, I try "startx" and it fails to start. I have checked the output of "journalctl -xb", but I understand nothing, as I am a novice Linux/Ubuntu user.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/UL9105RS) is the `journalctl -xb` output from yesterday.

What could I do?

Thank you very much,

mapm